# What is blocking AMQP TransportType when using Service Bus for Windows Server (Service Bus 1.1)?

Tags: .net, azure, firewall, amqp, servicebus

I have installed Service Bus for Windows Server (Service Bus 1.1) on my machine (Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 x64).

I am using the sample c# code to create a simple message sender/receiver as shown here:
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-advanced-message-queuing/

When I use the default `TransportType.NetMessaging` the console application runs fine and I can send/receive messages to my queue.

When I change the config file (or code) to use `TransportType.Amqp` the console application starts and I immediately get the exception:

```
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

(Note: this occurs when the `messageReceiver.Receive()` method is called).

It feels like a firewall/port blocked thing but the Service Bus install did successfully add a bunch of exceptions to my firewall that include:

```
SBHttpsPort [Inbound, Local Address=Any, Remote Address=Any, Protocol=TCP,9355, 9002, 9359, 9002]
Service Bus Gateway [Inbound, Local Address=Any, Remote Address=Any, Protocol=TCP, 9354, 5672, 5671]
Sevice Bus Message Broker [Inbound, Local Address=Any, Remote Address=Any, Protocol=TCP, 9356, 5672, 5671]
Service Bus Resource Provider [Inbound, Local Address=Any, Remote Address=Any, Protocol=TCP, 9359, 5672, 5671]
Service Bus VSS [Inbound, Local Address=Any, Remote Address=Any, Protocol=TCP, 9356, 5672, 5671]
```

There are also matching exceptions for the outbound rules.

```
Service Bus Gateway (out)
Sevice Bus Message Broker (out)
Service Bus Resource Provider (out)
Service Bus VSS (out)
```

I am on a corporate network so I cannot turn off the firewall to see what that does.

When I look in the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security->Monitoring->Firewall I do see the inbound exceptions for Service Bus but I don't see the Service Bus * (out) firewall exceptions (could this be the issue?).

Could anyone please help me figure out what is going on with Amqp on my machine?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use port 5671 for the RuntimePort.

If you are using a connection string, it should look like:

Endpoint=sb://machine1.contoso.com/ServiceBusDefaultNamespace;
StsEndpoint=https://machine1.contoso.com:9355/ServiceBusDefaultNamespace;
RuntimePort=5671;ManagementPort=9355;WindowsUsername=userName;WindowsDomain=contoso;
WindowsPassword=passssword; TransportType=Amqp

Comment: Is there a microsoft page that explains this?